# How can I restart activity on back button pressed?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm going from main activity to another activity and then when I press back button I want to go back to the main activity and restart it.
How can I do that?

Comment: If you don't explicitly shut down your first activity when entering the new one, this is the default behaviour.

Comment: @Jave He wants to restart it though.  It won't restart if he does what you said.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could just override the onBackButton pressed in your second activity to start the first one. Example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: If you are moving around a lot, your activity stack grows and grows, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it would. I interpreted the question as wanting to run through the onCreate code of the first activity again when pressing the back button. Normally, pressing the back button would just resume the activity. Using the code above would recreate the original activity. To fix the issue you brought up, you could simply finish the first activity after launching the second as others have brought up.

Answer (score 3):

When you press the back button while in the second activity, then Android automatically invokes the previous activity on the back stack, which is in your case your main activity.

For more information, see the Android docs for  [Tasks  and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Android calls the onResume() callback every time you return to an activity with the back button. Do all your "restart" work there.

Answer (score 3):

I was fiddling with this problem in the context of trying to reload my main activity after changing preferences in a custom PreferenceActivity and after some trial and error and reading other responses, this is what worked for me:

In my PreferenceActivity I use onBackPressed() to start my MainActivity (MainActivity.class is the activity I am returning to:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

In my MainActivity I'm calling my ReferenceActivity  (PreferenceSettings.class is the ReferenceActivity i'm going to through the function startSettings() through an onClick atrribute in my layout XML:

```
    public void startSettings(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreferenceSettings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

I use this to restart my MainActivity so it will run the onCreate() method again, reloading (refreshing) my views with any changes made in my PreferenceActivity. This causes my MainActivity to finish and unload when I start my ReferenceActivity, allowing it to be restarted through the back button being pressed from my PreferenceActivity. I am then refreshing the displayed values through the onCreate() method that loads the initial values from my SharedPreferences when the MainActivity is created.

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: I made a mistake in my code. I never called finish() in the onBackPressed() method in my PreferenceActivity. As a result, pressing the back button merely looped between the two Activities. You must call finish() in the onBackPressed() method inside the PreferenceActivity to remove it from the Activity stack. That way it is not still active when you press the back button in your MainActivity

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to override your `onBackPressed`. The method below works like a charm and is (imho) best practice.

in your `MainActivity` do this:

```
private static int CODE = 1; //declare as FIELD

startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class), CODE);
```

This will monitor if the user killed or quited the `SecondActivity`. You catch this by overriding `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity`

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         //SecondActivity closed
         if(requestCode == CODE){
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class)); //reload MainActivity
              finish();
         }
}
```

Comment: It's really doing the same thing as overriding onBackPressed. It's just a matter of where you put the code. I do agree this would work. But calling it a best practice, isn't really accurate. It's really up to the person implementing the logic.

Comment: Thank you for posting Mark I'll try that way also.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that **you have not shutdown the MainActivity** when you opened the current activity then this should work for you:

```
    @Override  
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
   {  
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
           finish();
           return true;
       }

       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

OR:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
 }
```

Comment: void function `onBackPressed()` can not return boolean